# Find elements by class using Xpath

Tags: html, xslt, xpath

I am trying to format and filter html into desired format by separating elements of specific class. My html input is as follows:

```
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;margin:0px;padding:0px">
<div class="pdf_page" id="pdf_page1" style="width:707px;height:1024px">
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text0" style="top:50px;left:688px">1</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text1" style="top:119px;left:96px">Healthcare 
Hospitals</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text4" style="top:190px;left:96px">PUBLIC 
HOSPITALS/MEDICAL CLINICS</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text5" style="top:207px;left:96px">Alexandra 
Hospital</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text5" style="top:224px;left:96px">Admiralty 
Medical Centre</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text5" style="top:241px;left:96px">Changi General 
Hospital</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text4" style="top:460px;left:96px">PRIVATE 
HOSPITALS/MEDICAL CLINICS</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text5" style="top:477px;left:96px">Farrer Park 
Hospital</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text5" style="top:494px;left:96px">Fortis Surgical 
Hospital</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text5" style="top:511px;left:96px">Gleneagles 
Hospital</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text4" style="top:662px;left:96px">DAY SURGERY 
CENTRES</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text5" style="top:679px;left:96px">A Clinic For 
Women</span>
<span class="pdf_text pdf_text5" style="top:696px;left:96px">A Company For 
Women</span>
</div>
...
```

I wrote below snippet to format it so that i can separate all Span's with class as 'pdf_text pdf_text4'

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <vce>
<xsl:apply-templates value="body" />
   </vce>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="div">
  <document>
    <content name="header">
      <xsl:value-of select="(//span[contains(@class, 'pdf_text pdf_text4')])" />
    </content>
    <content name="data">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
</content>
  </document>
</xsl:template>
```

But with this, I am getting output as follows:

```
<vce>
<document>
<content name="header">PUBLIC HOSPITALS/MEDICAL CLINICS</content>
<content name="data">
1 Healthcare List of M...
</content>
</document>
<document>
<content name="header">PUBLIC HOSPITALS/MEDICAL CLINICS</content>
<content name="data">
1 Healthcare List of M...
</content>
</document>
```

If you see above, "PUBLIC HOSPITALS/MEDICAL CLINICS" repeats again and again instead of picking next span content which has matching class.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared a script, in version *1.0*, based on *template recursion*.

The main template (matching "/") calls "normal" template to process only
`span` element with class *...text4*.

This "normal" template for *span*s first processes the own element
(creating *header*), then starts processing of following `span` elements
(with class *...text5*), by calling another template in *cell* mode,
to process the next sibling.
Due to recursion, this processing goes on while there is next sibling
with class *...text5*.

The "starting" recursive call (from "normal" template) is "enveloped" in
`<content name="data">` element.
For details see below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <vce><document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="body/div/span[contains(@class, 'text4')]"/>
    </document></vce>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="span">
    <!-- First process the current span (text4) -->
    <content name="header">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </content>
    <!-- Then, recursively, text5, starting from the next -->
    <content name="data">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="cell"/>
    </content>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Recursive processing of text5 spans -->
  <xsl:template match="span" mode="cell">
    <!-- Process the current span -->
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <!-- Find the next span (if any) -->
    <xsl:variable name="nextItem" select="following-sibling::*[1][self::span]
      [contains(@class, 'text5')]"/>
    <!-- Next span found -->
    <xsl:if test="$nextItem">
      <!-- Separator -->
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
      <!-- Process the next span -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$nextItem" mode="cell"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am getting compilation error for 'for-each-group'. I am using xsl 1.0.
I will still try few more things.
I want to group all spans in such a way that a span with class 'pdf_text4' will have all span's below it till I find next span with class as 'pdf_text4'

e.g.  
Header : PUBLIC HOSPITALS/MEDICAL CLINICS
data : Alexandra Hospital
Admiralty Medical Centre
Changi General Hospital

Header:PRIVATE HOSPITALS/MEDICAL CLINICS
data :Farrer Park Hospital
Fortis Surgical Hospital
Gleneagles Hospital

Comment: You should either have written that you use version 1.0 or have tagged the question with "XSLT 1.0". "Plain" XSLT tag suggests that the version doesn't matter. If the other answer is not enough, then for XSLT 1.0 solution search the web for *sibling recursion*. This is a method to do something like "grouping" in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks @validi_Bo. This was very helpful. My bad, I should have specified XSL version.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<xsl:value-of select="(descendant-or-self::span[contains(@class, 'pdf_text pdf_text4')])" />
```

instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="(//span[contains(@class, 'pdf_text pdf_text4')])" />
```

See Transformation at http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5vM

Comment: Thanks Rupesh, with fix that you have suggested, it picks only first span (matching to class) from each DIV tag. I get same output if I replace
    'code'<xsl:value-of select="(//span[contains(@class, 'pdf_text pdf_text4')])" />
with
    'code'<xsl:value-of select="(span[contains(@class, 'pdf_text pdf_text4')])" />

Please note, my input has multiple DIV tags within each DIV tag, there are many Span's.

Comment: See Transformation at [http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5vM](http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5vM)